# I need to fairly allocate a person in charge of each record but on a massive scale

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I need to fairly allocate a person in charge of each record but on a massive scale (unique select statement).

Below I present the form of it register by registry, in which I select the person in charge and increase the number of assignments to each record, so the next record will assign the manager who has fewer assignments. Please help.

```
BEGIN

FOR x in (
        SELECT COUNT(*) CANT,REG.CAUSEID,REG.OPTION_ID,REG.DATE
        FROM REGISTERS REG
        GROUP BY REG.CAUSEID,REG.OPTION_ID,REG.DATE
    )
loop

SELECT MANAGER,REGISTERID into V_MANAGERID,V_REGISTERID
FROM(
    SELECT MANAGER,
           REGISTERID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MANAGER ORDER BY CANT_REGISTERS ASC NULLS LAST) ORDER
    FROM MANAGERS MA
    WHERE MA.FECHA = TRUNC(x.DATE)
    AND MA.OPTION=x.OPTION_ID
)
WHERE ORDER=1;

UPDATE REGISTERS   
SET MANAGERID=V_MANAGERID
WHERE CAUSEID=x.CAUSEID;        

UPDATE MANAGERS
SET CANT_REGISTERS = NVL(CANT_REGISTERS,0) + x.CANT
WHERE REGISTERID=V_REGISTERID;  

end loop; 

END;
```

Comment: Why the Java tag?

Comment: I just corrected it, thank you very much.

Comment: Not ckear what you want, Can youplease elaborate `on a massive scale`

Comment: I need in a statement to get the managers associated with each record, but for each record I must assign the manager who has fewer assignments.

example:

    causeid, manager, CANT_REGISTERS
    1 manager1 1
    2 manager2 1
    3 manager3 1

the next manager should be the one with the least assignments and so on.